# Unused columns in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery, sqlite, relational-theory

I found this query in our codebase:

```sql
DELETE FROM "Foo"
WHERE ("Foo"."Id", "Foo"."CreatedAt")
IN (SELECT "f"."Id", "f"."CreatedAt"
    FROM "Foo" AS "f"
    WHERE "f"."CreatedAt" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

It deletes records created before the current time.

This gives the same result:

```sql
DELETE FROM "Foo"
WHERE "Foo"."CreatedAt"
IN (SELECT "f"."CreatedAt"
    FROM "Foo" AS "f"
    WHERE "f"."CreatedAt" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I don't know why the `Foo.Id` is included in the `WHERE` clause - maybe leftover junk from various refactorings (e.g. it could have been used for batch delete with `ORDER BY "f"."Id" LIMIT 1000`). But because it's a PK, I'm reluctant to remove it, as maybe it's there for a reason.

Is there a theoretical / perf reason for having it in there, or are the two queries equivalent?

(This targets both postgres and sqlite.)

Comment: What will happen to the record that has `Id = NULL`? What will happen to the record that has `CreatedAt = NULL`? Think. Then test both queries...

Comment: @Akina Thanks that is a good tip. In this case though they are both declared as non-null.

Comment: You may be right about `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` in a historical version. Sqlite allows you to use those clauses directly in `DELETE` without a subquery, but maybe PostgreSQL doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both queries are ridiculously complicated. Use

```
DELETE FROM "Foo"
WHERE "CreatedAt" < current_timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, your query has made my work much simpler! But for my education, are the ones I posted theoretically the same, or is there some difference between them? The PK in there is what confused me.

Comment: They do the same thing, albeit in a more complicated fashion with a self-join. The two queries in your question are different, but have the same effect. As you suspect, there is no good reason to use the primary key.